# numpy array concatenate with extra column to each array

Tags: numpy

I try to split a numPy array in roughly equal parts and merge them together with an extra value but end up being confused how I could do this. I have a list : [0., 2.25, 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 2.25], which after an np.array_split and concatenate with an extra column should end up like: [0.  , 2.25, 4., 8., 4., 4., 4., 8., 4., 4., 8., 4.  , 2.25]

The steps I took:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list = [0., 2.25, 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 2.25]
>>> x = np.array(list)
>>> print(x)
[0.   2.25 4.   4.   4.   4.   4.   4.   4.   2.25]
>>> x = np.array_split(list, 4)
>>> print(x)
[array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  ]), array([4., 4., 4.]), array([4., 4.]), 
array([4.  , 2.25])]
>>> x = np.concatenate([x, 8])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

When I keep the array in the same shape, it will add it to the end of the list

```
>>> x = np.concatenate([[x, y]])
>>> print(x)
[list([array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  ]), array([4., 4., 4.]), array([4., 
4.]), array([4.  , 2.25])])
 list([8])]
```

I understand that it might be more easy to do so, if you know the shape of the individual arrays and so you could add an extra column with the single value of 8 but array_split doesn't have equal sizes as seen above.

Do I miss a step over here, is it even possible what I want to achieve?

Comment: Did you mean your desired output to have an 8 at the end like [0. , 2.25, 4., 8., 4., 4., 4., 8., 4., 4., 8., 4. , 2.25, 8] ?

Comment: Concatenate takes a list as input.  It joins the elements of that list.  If the elements are not arrays it first makes them arrays.  What is `np.array(x)` and `np.array(8)`?  Do they have the same number of dimensions?

Comment: @skmth no, the last 8 is not needed, the desired output is: [0. , 2.25, 4., 8., 4., 4., 4., 8., 4., 4., 8., 4. , 2.25]

Comment: @hpaulj the length of the list nor the amount of array_splits are known. I get a list of numbers, which I need to convert to the desired output. The only fixed known numbers are 0 and 2.25

Comment: I didn't ask for the length of the list.  I want the number of dimensions of the 2 `np.array` operations.  That's the root of the dimension error.  Number of dimensions is different from the `shape` which is different from the length.

Comment: @hpaulj (x = np.array(list)) -> x.ndim => 1 // (x = np.array_split(list, 4)) -> x.dim => AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: `np.array_split` creates a list; and yes a list does not have a `shape` or `ndim`.  It isn't an array.  But `np.array(np.array_split...)` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [71]: alist = [0., 2.25, 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 2.25]
In [72]: x = np.array(alist)
In [73]: xs = np.array_split(x, 4)
In [75]: xs
Out[75]: 
[array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  ]),
 array([4., 4., 4.]),
 array([4., 4.]),
 array([4.  , 2.25])]
```

`xs` is a list of arrays of differing size; `concatenate` can join them on their 1d dimension, recreating `x`.

```
In [76]: np.concatenate(xs)
Out[76]: array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  , 4.  , 4.  , 4.  , 4.  , 4.  , 4.  , 2.25])
```

Notice what happens when I try to create an array from `xs`:

```
In [77]: np.array(xs)
Out[77]: 
array([array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  ]), array([4., 4., 4.]), array([4., 4.]),
       array([4.  , 2.25])], dtype=object)
```

The result is a 1d object dtype array, containing those arrays.  But if the split had produced equal size arrays, the result would be 2d

```
In [79]: np.array_split(x,5)
Out[79]: 
[array([0.  , 2.25]),
 array([4., 4.]),
 array([4., 4.]),
 array([4., 4.]),
 array([4.  , 2.25])]
In [80]: np.array(np.array_split(x,5))
Out[80]: 
array([[0.  , 2.25],
       [4.  , 4.  ],
       [4.  , 4.  ],
       [4.  , 4.  ],
       [4.  , 2.25]])
```

`np.concatenate([xs, 8])` is really `np.concatenate([np.array(xs), np.array(8)])`, joining a 1d object array with a 0d integer array.  Hence the dimension error.

To produce the array you want, you need to add the 8 to the desired arrays, and then concatenate.

```
In [84]: for i,v in enumerate(xs[:-1]):
    ...:     xs[i] = np.concatenate([v,[8]])
    ...:     
In [85]: xs
Out[85]: 
[array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  , 8.  ]),
 array([4., 4., 4., 8.]),
 array([4., 4., 8.]),
 array([4.  , 2.25])]
In [86]: np.concatenate(xs)
Out[86]: 
array([0.  , 2.25, 4.  , 8.  , 4.  , 4.  , 4.  , 8.  , 4.  , 4.  , 8.  ,
       4.  , 2.25])
```

Or add 8 to all, and drop the last 8 after concatenation.

Comment: @hjpaul, thank you for the in-depth explanation, could one say that a list is a 1D array in NumPy?

Comment: @ian, a list of numbers becomes a 1d array.  But a list of lists might become 2d or other.  Practice with `np.array()` and various inputs.  You don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead not just do

```
np.insert(list, [3,6,8],[8])
array([ 0.  ,  2.25,  4.  ,  8.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ,  8.  ,  4.  ,
        4.  ,  8.  ,  4.  ,  2.25,  8.  ])
```

np.array_split produces a list of split array. So to get your desired result you would have to do

```
[np.concatenate((i,[8])) for i in x]

[array([ 0.  ,  2.25,  4.  ,  8.  ]),
 array([ 4.,  4.,  4.,  8.]),
 array([ 4.,  4.,  8.]),
 array([ 4.  ,  2.25,  8.  ])]
```

Comment: yeah @kmario23 .. I don't see how else to concatenate list of arrays than just looping over as above

Comment: @skmth, the desired output is a ravel() of the array, I might be able to remove the last 8 from the list in the next step. The np.insert has fixed positions but I need to get those positions from the array_split action to know where the 8's are needed.